# Android Management API WebApp create/patch failed with HTTP error code 503

Tags: android-management-api

I have an issue with Android Management API when trying to create/patch a WebApp with an icon. If the imageData is not correct, the API returns a detailed error but if the imageData is encoded as expected, the API returns a HTTP 503 error code with message **"The service is currently unavailable."**. I thought this error would be transient but the REST calls seem to always fail. Any information could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has been fixed. We no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when adding icons on AMAPI webApps. This issue is still pending in our Engineering’s backlog, Unfortunately, we have no shareable timeline or additional info.

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.

Comment: Hi @ct06fr This issue has been fixed. Please ensure that your image is a png or jpg (ideally 512px square) and has max size 1 MB or smaller. For more information [WebAppIcon](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webApps#webappicon)

Comment: Hi @Rey V. Aquino, I just tried again with a square 512x512 png image (less than 1MB) and still have the same 'The service is currently unavailable' error.

Comment: I confirm that errors do not appear anymore. Thanks.